# what is different between 'in need of' and 'need'?

Tags: grammar

Here is some example sentence,

> She's been taking care of the whole family and is really *in need of* some me time!

What is the special reason of using "in need of" instead of need?

Comment: If you change "need" to "needs" there is absolutely no difference. "Needs" means "in need of". "Need" is grammatically incorrect due to singular noun requires a singular verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent sentence using "needs" would be:

> She's been taking care of the whole family and really needs some me time!

This has exactly the same meaning, and both are gramatically correct.

The difference is subtle: "...is really in need of..." places emphasis on this woman being in a state of requiring the me time.